# How to inflate xml-layout into child View

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater

I'm trying to inflate xml-layout into custom View-class, which is then placed into LinearLayout in actual software. After some Googling I managed to create custom class which inflates the layout by using following class:

```
    public class LitteringView extends RelativeLayout
{

    public LitteringView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.littering_layout, this);

    }


    public LitteringView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         for(int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++){
             getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
         }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }





}
```

Now it definitely inflates when I add it to the linearlayout:

```
layout.addView(new LitteringView(getActivity()));
```

Problem is that it takes the whole screen while the screen should be divided equally between LinearLayout's three children. Other Views are also created dynamically. How I can prevent it from taking the whole space?

I'm trying to create one custom View/class and package its functions inside it which I then could easily add to the parent layout (in this case the LinearLayout) while wanting to utilize xml to define the layout of the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'weight' for your views. A simple example for this:

```
Layout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, weight);
```

You need to optimize it for your case. Give all your views a weight value equally(eg: 1 for all of them) and they should share the view.